# Неявная обработка NTLM авторизации в браузере chrome

Tags: c#, браузер, ntlm

Есть небольшой сайт с доменной авторизацией.

Когда открываешь страницу в последнем Firefox - тебя спрашивает логин/пароль, после чего переходишь на сайт. Всё работает, всё хорошо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно попробовать сделать запрос к сайту из кода на c#. Указываешь NTLM авторизацию - при указании корректных данных работает, при некорретных - выдаёт 401 Unauthorized, всё логично.

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("AK", "password", "domain");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials, UseDefaultCredentials = false };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
return await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Но вот если я открываю хром, чищу кукисы -- то никакого окна с логином/паролем не выдаётся -- даже в приватном режиме, даже при том, что инспектор показывает, что нет заголовка с NTLM авторизацией.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как хром делает такое? И насколько правдиво показывает информацию о запросе?

Comment: Хром обманывает. Он шлёт два запроса, первый из которых получает от сервера 401 с WWW-Authenticate. В инспекторе показываются не все запросы и не все заголовки. Хотите увидеть все - возьмите fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Перенес в ответ из комментария @PashaPash чтобы вопрос имел ответ и не был удалён духом сообщества:

Хром обманывает. Он шлёт два запроса, первый из которых получает от сервера 401 с WWW-Authenticate. В инспекторе показываются не все запросы и не все заголовки. Хотите увидеть все - возьмите fiddler.