# Одновременно две схемы аутентификации в asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

У меня есть некоторое работающее приложение asp.net core использующее asp.net identity (app-in user store)

Я хотел бы добавить к нему набор api контроллеров с jwt аутентификацией для небольшой админки написанной на vue.js - но при этом оставить возможность использовать cookie аутентификацию для "обычного" входа на веб-сайт.

Насколько я понимаю, в принципе, такое возможно - см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Делал по аналогии:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login"; })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer    = AuthOptions.ISSUER,

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience    = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
                ValidateLifetime = true,

                IssuerSigningKey         = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            };
        });
```

Однако как я не пытался - у меня всё время отваливается какая-нибудь аутентификация:

- либо jwt работает, но при логине на сайт после ввода логина-пароля на странице /Identity/Account/Login снова кидает на эту же страницу с просьбой ввести логин-пароль.
- либо логин на сайт проходит успешно, но jwt-токен не проверяется и можно любым неаутентифицированным пользователям иметь доступ к всему api

Я даже отдельную тему [подымал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/927556/213987) с тем, как написать тесты, чтобы иметь уверенность, что ничего не отвалится - где @PashaPash аргументировал, что такие тесты писать вообще не нужно.

Что делать? Куда смотреть?

Реализация токенов у меня сделана как в букварях ([тынц](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.7.php)), практически такая же есть и @tym32167 в [его ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852085/213987)

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно было просто указать api контроллерам, что они ходят строго через jwt - и всё сразу заработало:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] // <-- That's all, folks! :)
public class BrandController : Controller
{
}
```

В каких иногда мелочах кроется разгадка...