# Логирование в IIS6 при использовании доменной авторизации на сайте (ошибки при авторизации)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, логирование, iis

Проблема в следующем: есть .NET приложение (C#), развернутое во внутренней сети компании, настроена доменная авторизация. При работе с сайтом (вход на сайт осуществляется по ip-адресу: http://XX.XX.XX.XX:2020), для некоторых пользователей (все находятся в домене) в логах IIS появляются такие строки:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2021-03-02 01:04:58
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
    
2021-03-02 03:01:27 W3SVC611874432 10.XX.XX.XX POST / - 2020 - 10.YY.YY.YY Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 401 2 2148074254   
2021-03-02 03:01:27 W3SVC611874432 10.XX.XX.XX POST / - 2020 - 10.YY.YY.YY Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 401 1 0    
2021-03-02 03:01:27 W3SVC611874432 10.XX.XX.XX POST / - 2020 DOMAIN\User 10.YY.YY.YY Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 200 0 0
```

в то время как для других пользователей всего 1 строка:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2021-03-02 01:04:58
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
 
2021-03-02 03:02:21 W3SVC611874432 10.XX.XX.XX POST / - 2020 DOMAIN\User 10.YY.YY.YY Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 200 0 0
```

С чем связано такое поведение? Так должно быть, т.к. сервер обменивается с клиентом аутентификационными данными, либо у меня что-то не так настроено (2 раза клиенту возвращается 401 код и лишь в 3-й раз клиент получает код 200)? Могут ли из-за таких действий пропадать данные, переданные в первичном POST-запросе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В двух словах: это правильно и соответствует RFCI на протокол NTLM.

Я как-то похожими вопросами интересовался:

- [Неявная обработка NTLM авторизации в браузере chrome](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/906910/213987)
- [Откуда лишний запрос при NTLM авторизации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907298/213987)

в них есть ссылка на майкрософтовский сайт с этими RFCI, можете нырнуть сами и узнать как глубока кроличья нора.

Если же кратко, то верхний пример - это полный цикл браузера ([хром врёт, запросов реально три - смотрите в Firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906910/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-ntlm-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-chrome#comment1489822_906910)), а нижний - это в браузере ещё валидная авторизационная информация с контроллера домена осталась.

> Могут ли из-за таких действий пропадать данные, переданные в первичном POST-запросе?

Современные браузеры нормально обрабатывают, ничего не теряют.

Comment: Спасибо, прочитал информацию по Вашим ссылкам - то что нужно! Но в одной из ссылок заметил вопрос, на который не увидел четкого ответа и который так же косвенно относится к моему вопросу - почему в некоторых случаях при NTLM - авторизации происходит запрос логина и пароля у клиента, а при некоторых нет? Например, у нас web-приложение доступно по доменному имени и все сотрудники по нему замечательно попадают на сайт, но стоит пользователям зайти по ip-адресу, а не по dns-имени - у некоторых появляется запрос доменных логина и пароля. Почему не срабатывает сквозная авторизация?

Comment: @Andrew_1992 Браузер не запрашивает на каждый запрос информацию с контроллера домена, а умеет хранить авторизационную инфорацию (и сама операционная система пользователя умеет кешировать), поэтому не теребит юзера "а введи ещё раз пароль". Я об этом написал про два ваших скрина. Пример, который вы привели про "IP vs доменное имя" тут просто мимо кассы: для браузера это совершенно другой сайт. Вы же понимаете, что в словаре где ключом выступает строка (имя сайта) это просто разные строки? Браузер не dns, он не знает про все 15 IP-адресов фейсбука и не обязан. Другой сайт - вводи пароль снова.

Comment: Про то, что браузер считает сайт с ip-адресом другим сайтом, согласен, это логично, но почему не происходит сквозной авторизации? У меня данные УЗ не запрашивались даже при первичном входе на web-ресурс, а у другого пользователя запрашиваются при каждом входе на сайт после закрытия/открытия браузера. Я не совсем улавливаю логику в этом... Просто при входе по ip/не по ip это более ярко выражено и я предположил что дело в этом

Comment: @Andrew_1992 Понятия не имею, попробуйте поискать сами. Проверьте например, что браузер тот же: возможно не запрашиваются в IE (MS сделала более бесшовную интеграцию), а из Firefox запрашивается чаще. Возможно, политика внутри браузера "чистить авторизацию после закрытия браузера". Слишком много деталей надо сравнить, это вы сами возьмите две машины и пока не добьётесь воспроизводимого примера, в чём точно отличие не стоит и пытаться со стороны теории объяснить. Ведь вы же по сути что просите меня? У меня не знаю, что - скажи почему? Это лишь вера в эксперта: похоже, правдоподобно  - поверил.

Comment: Спасибо за хорошие мысли, буду смотреть в этом направлении